# Why an array reference is passed in the method instead of its values?

Tags: java, arrays

I am declaring an array `myArray` in main method and passed the same array in `doIt(myArray)` method.

When I took another array variable in `doIt()` method and assign `myArray` to it. And then I printed the `myArray` in main method.

But I am doing same thing with `integer` and `String`, the changes made in respective method do not affect the output.

My Code is

```java
public class ChangeIt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = {1,2,3,4,5};

        new ChangeIt().doIt(myArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
        }

        String str= "Gaurav";
        new ChangeIt().printString(str);
        System.out.println("\n"+ str);

        int num = 5;
        new ChangeIt().printNum(num);
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    private void doIt(int[] z) {
        int[] A = z;
        A[0] = 99;

    }
    private void printString(String s){
        String s2 = s + "Kukade";
    }

    private void printNum(int x) {
        int y = x+1;
    }

}
```

The output is

```
99 2 3 4 5
Gaurav
5
```

So, what is happening? Why it is printing `99` instead of `1`?

Comment: In the other two cases, you're creating new instance. In the `doIt()` method, you are just creating new variable, which points to the same instance of an array. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1

Comment: There is a difference between *reasigning* new value and *modifying* existing value. If you want your wife to have blond hair you can either `wife = new Wife(HairColor.BLOND)` (divorce and remarry blonde) or `whife.hairColor(HairColor.BLOND);` (let your wife change her hair). Second approach (modification) also uses reassignment but it does it on object internal property (hair color) - which represents its state.

Comment: Thanks for your comment NeplatnyUdaj and Pshemo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I am doing same thing with integer and String, the changes made in respective method do not affect the output.

The fundamental difference is that with the `int` and `String`, you're not changing the state of the original `int` or `String`. In fact, you're not even assigning to the parameter (but if you did, it wouldn't be observable outside the function).

But with the array, you're changing the *state* of the array, not assigning a new array to a local.

This:

```
int[] A = z;
```

just points `A` at the same array `z` points to, it doesn't create a *new* array. Since they both point to the original array, assigning to one of its elements changes the state of the array.